# How to return found values from one query when the others return #N/A using Google Sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, this formula has 3 `QUERY()` wrapped into one so that the results are vertically set. The problem is that when one of the queries doesn't find any values, it returns a `#VALUE` saying: `In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.`

I've tried `IFERROR()`, wrapping it all in anothe r`QUERY()`, but it doesn't work.

```
=QUERY({
query({Sheet1!A:FR},"Select Col142,Col11,Col12,Col74 where Col7 = '"&P4&"' and not Col142 contains '#N/A' and not Col142 matches '-' and Col142 is not null",0);
query({Sheet1!A:FR},"Select Col150,Col11,Col12,Col78 where Col7 = '"&P4&"' and not Col150 contains '#N/A' and not Col150 matches '-' and Col150 is not null",0);
query({Sheet1!A:FR},"Select Col152,Col11,Col12,Col82 where Col7 = '"&P4&"' and not Col152 contains '#N/A' and not Col152 matches '-' and Col152 is not null",0)
},"select * where Col1 <> '#N/A' and Col1 is not ''")
```

Appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply iferror on each individual query and give a complete row of blanks, that is

```
iferror(query(_____________),{"","","",""})
```

if query is supposed to fetch 4 results per row